# Usage of check up with verbs

Tags: phrase-usage

I know that I can use, give a check up, get a check up  or have a check up. ( medical) . But can I use the phrase.   ...take a check up. If so , what would the meaning be? Place help

Comment: Have you ever seen "take a check up" used in context? if so, please provide the source and context. If not explain where this question is coming from. Why do you suppose it could be idiomatic? Why do you think it might not be?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not in common use. I simply can’t think of a way to use it and can’t recall hearing it in any context.

It doesn’t work if “take” is being used somewhat figuratively, as it is in these phases:

- Take a break
- Take a walk
- Take a tram
- Take a breather
- Take a vacation

It is even less likely if used more literally as in:

- Take a cookie
- Take a child to school
- Take a book from the shelf

Comment: It's certainly not normal but I'm sure you could find some context when it could occur. One example is the expression "I'll take the/that X now" meaning, I'll take up your offer now. So if someone has been badgering you for months to have a check-up and you want them to do it now, you could say "I'll take the check-up now."

Answer (score 0):

When you **take** something, you are actively performing the action, and you don't need anyone else to complete it.

> I'm taking this cookie.

When you **get** something, you're typically *receiving* something from another person, who is required to complete the action. For example:

> I'm getting 5 cookies from Martha.

With **get**, the person you're receiving from is often omitted because it's a logical assumption and not important to the conversation.

> I'm getting a checkup.

You are *receiving* the checkup. It's assumed that a doctor is required to complete the checkup.

Answer (score 0):

In certain phrases, “take” can mean “be the recipient of an action”.  You can “take a blow to the head”, for example.  You can “take a beating”.  You can “take a mark on your record”.

I cannot think of use of this passive take where the thing taken is positive, or even neutral, so no, you can “take a check-up”.